# PHP CLI continue checking MYSQL database every 2 seconds until user decided to quit

Tags: php

I don't very much find too much information over the internet about PHP CLI so I am having a hard time figuring out how to finish my code.

Basically, the application should continue checking the MYSQL database every 2 seconds without exiting, unless otherwise the user entered the letter 'q'.

I started it out by just printing the word 'pro' continuously before I implement MYSQL so my code looked like this:

```
<?php
    fwrite(STDOUT, "This should print word 'pro' continuously\n");
    fwrite(STDOUT, "\tto exit, simply press 'q' and enter\n");

    do {
        fwrite(STDOUT, "pro\n");
    }while (fgetc(STDIN) != 'q');
?>
```

Pretty much when the user entered 'q', the app terminates, but the problem is it only prints  out 'pro' once, and when I pressed enter.

Comment: the code given above is only an example to check for a continuous process. I haven't implemented MySQL yet so it would easy to debug.

Comment: this could be useful https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgetc()` will block until there is data to read - in other words, when the script reaches the `fgetc()` call, the execution will halt until the user inputs something.

In order to work around this, you will need to check whether there is any data to read using [`stream_select()`](http://php.net/stream-select). You can also use `stream_select()` to limit the MySQL poll to every 2 seconds. A basic framework would look something like this:

```
<?php

  // Do all your init work here, connect to DB etc
  $tickerSecs = 2;
  echo "Hello! I've started\n";

  do {

    // Do actual work here
    echo "I'm polling the database\n";

    // See stream_select() docs for an explanation of why this is necessary
    $r = array(STDIN);
    $w = $e = NULL;
    if (stream_select($r, $w, $e, $tickerSecs) > 0) {
      // The user input something
      echo "You input something\n";
      $char = fread(STDIN, 1);
      if ($char == 'q') {
        // The user pressed 'q'
        echo "You told me to quit\n";
        break;
      } else {
        echo "I don't understand '$char'\n";
      }
    }

  } while (TRUE); // Loop forever

  // Do shutdown work here
  echo "I'm shutting down\n";
```

Note that it is likely that you will have to require your user to press `q + enter` rather than just `q` because of the nature of the way these things work - and I don't really understand why this is, maybe someone else can provide the missing piece here?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than stopping when Q is pressed, you could use pcntl_signal() to register a handler for SIGQUIT (ie Ctrl-C)